# What HTTP status code should I use for nickname validation?

Tags: validation, api, rest, standards

I am building an API and one of the endpoints is about nickname validation for a company. I read a lot about HTTP status codes and for entity validation `422` seems the best choice. How about one field validation as in my example?

Comment: Are you sure about `422`? Wikipedia says something else:
"422 Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV; RFC 4918)
The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.[4]"

I'd consider a normal `200 OK` for success and maybe `401 Unauthorized` for the error state?

Comment: Which factors determine whether or not a nickname is valid?

Comment: @ROAL how do you figure what status code to return if you don't know what determines the status?

Comment: @Tim Castelijns For example it already exists or has not allowed chars

Comment: @TimCastelijns it was just a wild guess: "User exists/validation is ok" = `200 OK` as everything is fine. "User does not exist/validation is incorrect" = `401 Unauthorized` as the authorization process either failed or did not occur at all. Of course, as I said, it's just a wild guess, what popped up in my mind. And given the answer below, I clearly did not have the same idea as OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What HTTP status code should I use for nickname validation?

---

> For example it already exists

I think [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) is an appropriate pick

> The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict.

User 1 picked a username, User 2 wants the same, but can't, because it *conflicts* with User 1's username

> or has not allowed chars

For this, [422 Unprocessable Entity](http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity) as you mentioned seems ok.

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code **means the server understands the content type of the request entity** (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and **the syntax of the request entity is correct** (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions. For example, **this error condition may occur if request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, instructions.**

Emphasis mine